# Call function php uing jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hello i want to call a function using jquery. I tried a lot of ways and I can't get it.
This my principal webpage. 
I'am uploading a file csv and pressing 'Crear' button, it uplaod the file while call the function.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
       $(function (){
          $('#btnxml').click(function (){
             alert("aki");
             $('#contenidos').load('csv.php');
         });
      });
   </SCRIPT>
   </head>
   <body>
                        <form action="index.php" id="filecsv"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                         <input type="file" multiple="multiple" id="file" name="up_csv[]"/>
                         <input type="submit" value="Cargar" name="btnxml" id="btnxml" /><br />
                         </form>
                          <?php
                         global $archivocsv;
                            //tipos de archivos permitidos
                   $extensionxml = array('csv','txt');
                   //destino
                   $rutaupcsv = './csv/';
                   //multicargador de archivos
                   $vt=0;
                   for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['up_csv']['size']);$i++){
                       for ($j=-1; $j<count($extensionxml); $j++) {
                           if (strripos($_FILES['up_csv']['name'][$i], $extensionxml[$j])!== false)  {
                               $filename = 'lista';
                           $destino = $rutaupcsv.$_FILES['up_csv']['name'][$i];
                           $archivocsv = basename($_FILES['up_csv']['name'][$i]);
                           move_uploaded_file($_FILES['up_csv']['tmp_name'][$i],$destino);
                           $vt=$vt+1;   
                           break; 
                           }
                           $ns=1;
                           }
                           }
                          ?>
                        <div id="contenidos"></div>
```

csv.php

```
              <?php
        echo '<html>';
        echo '<head>';
         echo '<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">';
          echo '<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">';
          echo '</head>'; 
          function makecsv() {
            global $archivocsv;
           $csv = './csv/' . $archivocsv;
           $doc = new DOMDocument();

          $row = 1;
          $handle = fopen($csv, "r");
         # Rows Counter
         $csvxrow = file($csv);
          $csvxrow[0] = chop($csvxrow[0]);
        $anzdata = count($csvxrow);
       while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
         $num = count($data);
         $row++;
             #Load Predefined XML Template      
             $xml2 = $xml;
             $xmlruta = './Templates/';
             $xml = $xmlruta.$data[1].'.xml';
              $doc->load($xml);  
              $xp = new DOMXPath($doc);
            for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {

              foreach($xp->query('/ROOT/HEADER/@KEY[. != ""]') as $attrib)
              {
              $attrib->nodeValue = $data[0];
              }
               foreach($xp->query('/ROOT/DATA/SAPMES/LOIPRO/E1FKOL/@AUFNR[. != ""]') as $attrib)
              {
              $attrib->nodeValue = $data[0];
              }
              foreach($xp->query('/ROOT/DATA/SAPMES/LOIPRO/E1FKOL/@MATNR[. != ""]') as $attrib)
               {
               $attrib->nodeValue = $data[1];
              }
               foreach($xp->query('/ROOT/DATA/SAPMES/LOIPRO/E1FKOL/@GAMNG[. != ""]') as $attrib)
              {
               $attrib->nodeValue = $data[2];
               }
              foreach($xp->query('/ROOT/DATA/SAPMES/LOIPRO/E1AFFLL/E1FVOL/@MGVRG[. != ""]') as $attrib)
              {
                 $attrib->nodeValue = $data[2];
               }
                 foreach($xp->query('/ROOT/DATA/SAPMES/LOIPRO/E1FKOL/@GSTRS[. != ""]') as $attrib)
             {
                   $attrib->nodeValue = $data[3];
                   }
                   foreach($xp->query('/ROOT/DATA/SAPMES/LOIPRO/E1FKOL/@GLTRS[. != ""]') as $attrib)
                   {
                $fecha = new DateTime($data[3]);
                $fecha->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
                 $attrib->nodeValue = $fecha->format('Y-m-d');
                    }
              }
                     $name = $data[0] .'-'. $data[1];
                     $doc->formatOutput = true;
                echo $doc->saveXML();
                     $rutafinal = './XML/';
                     $doc->save($rutafinal.$name.'.xml');

                    }
                  fclose($handle);

                 echo $anzdata . " XML Creados" . "<br />";  

                 return $data;
                }
                   makecsv();
                   echo '</html>';
                 ?>
```

I can't call the function.
it doesn't do anything when i try to call it.

EDIT: I think the problem is in my function. function edite

Comment: How about sharing the code for it then

Comment: To clarify: Do you want to call a PHP function from within Javascript, or run the function when the CSV file has been uploaded?

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console? Ctrl+Shift+J will bring it up on most browsers.

Comment: Well. Upload the csv file... and then use it in php function...

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can´t play with php directly because JS is client side (only in browser) and PHP is server side (only in browser). What you can do is a PHP file that has the code you want to invoke, and make JS call that page.

Separate the CVS code from the form and make JS call the new php with the CVS php functionality.

Comment: OP is using `.load()` to do that.

Comment: You have the JS and PHP in the same file. I mean you need to separate. JS can´t call PHP funcions just manipulate DOM and make async http requests.

Comment: BTW, you are not posting anything from the form to the php file. Using the Load methos you are loading but not posting the file to the server.

Comment: Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery runs in the client's browser whereas your PHP is running on your web server. If you wish to call a PHP function from your jQuery code, your best option is to do so using AJAX.

You can find documentation for implementing an AJAX call in jQuery here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to print the actual hmtl to do the function.

**PHP**

```
<?php
    print '<script> makecsv() </script>';
?>
```

Comment: I think it is a PHP function, not a JavaScript function.

Comment: Ah, perhaps. I read it as calling a JS function in PHP at first, but re-reading it, I think you might be right.

Comment: Yeah, php function. i've been trying to call php function when my csv file is uploaded